# Inline Horizontal Buttons in SwiftUI Menu

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, menu, ipados

In SwiftUI, there is a thing called a Menu, and in it you can have Buttons, Dividers, other Menus, etc. Here's an example of one I'm building below:

```swift
import SwiftUI

func testing() {
    print("Hello")
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Menu {
                Button(action: testing) {
                    Label("Button 1", systemImage: "pencil.tip.crop.circle.badge.plus")
                }
                Button(action: testing) {
                    Label("Button 2", systemImage: "doc")
                }
            }
        label: {
            Label("", systemImage: "ellipsis.circle")
        }
        }
    }
}
```

So, in the SwiftUI Playgrounds app, they have this menu:

[image]

My question is:

**How did they make the circled menu option?** I’ve found a few other cases of this horizontal set of buttons in a Menu, like this one below:

[image]

HStacks and other obvious attempts have all failed. I’ve looked at adding a MenuStyle, but the Apple’s docs on that are very lacking, only showing an example of adding a red border to the menu button. Not sure that’s the right path anyway.

I’ve only been able to get Dividers() and Buttons() to show up in the Menu:

[image]

I’ve also only been able to find code examples that show those two, despite seeing examples of other options in Apps out there.

Comment: Here’s some random SwiftUI Code with a Menu I’ve been playing around with if it’s helpful: https://gist.github.com/adammenges/a8cc0dd63fe8d13ad5e5819b9ea31057

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. All code should be included in the question.

Comment: Show us what you've already tried. What result did you see?

Comment: Added what I see!

Comment: This is a tough question, I tried Sections and Pickers to no avail. The UIKit equivalent is `UIMenuElementSizeSmall` which might help in the search. What SwiftUI apps have you seen it in? We can decompile them and figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as this is only available in `UIKit` at present (and only iOS 16+), by setting

```
menu.preferredElementSize = .medium
```

To add this to your app you can add a `UIMenu` to `UIButton` and then use `UIHostingController` to add it to your SwiftUI app.

Here's an example implementation:

**Subclass a UIButton**

```
class MenuButton: UIButton {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let inspectAction = self.inspectAction()
        let duplicateAction = self.duplicateAction()
        let deleteAction = self.deleteAction()

        setImage(UIImage(systemName: "ellipsis.circle"), for: .normal)
        menu = UIMenu(title: "", children: [inspectAction, duplicateAction, deleteAction])
        menu?.preferredElementSize = .medium
        showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true

    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func inspectAction() -> UIAction {
        UIAction(title: "Inspect",
                 image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up.square")) { action in
           //
        }
    }
        
    func duplicateAction() -> UIAction {
        UIAction(title: "Duplicate",
                 image: UIImage(systemName: "plus.square.on.square")) { action in
           //
        }
    }
        
    func deleteAction() -> UIAction {
        UIAction(title: "Delete",
                 image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"),
            attributes: .destructive) { action in
           //
        }
    }

}
```

**Create a `Menu` using UIViewRepresentable**

```
struct Menu: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MenuButton {
        MenuButton(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MenuButton, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

**Works like a charm!**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Menu()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh sweet! Thanks! How would you add more regular buttons below the three you’ve got there? Like in the second screenshot.

Comment: Apple have a whole downloadable project with all sorts of menus. I'd suggest installing that and see what they do. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/adding_context_menus_in_your_app

Answer (score 14):

Starting with **iOS 16.4 / macOS 13.3**, it is possible to accomplish this by using [`ControlGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/controlgroup) in a `Menu`.

```swift
Menu {
    ControlGroup {
        Button { } label: {
            Image(systemName: "1.circle.fill")
        }

        Button { } label: {
            Image(systemName: "2.circle.fill")
        }

        Button { } label: {
            Image(systemName: "3.circle.fill")
        }                  
    }
}
```

You can add the [`.controlGroupStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/controlgroupstyle) modifier to the `ControlGroup` to change how the buttons appear. `.menu` is the default style. You can place up to three buttons side-by-side with `.menu`, or up to four with `.compactMenu`.

[image]

Comment: in the documentation it says it's available in **iOS15** already

Comment: @boweidmann `ControlGroup` has been available since iOS 15, but it is multi-purpose. It only produces the desired functionality in iOS 17 and above.